# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Urn

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, smo

I have the SQL2008 version of SMO and although it uses this class internally I can't figure how to bring it into scope so I can declare variables to hold values of this type.

Yes I know I could declare them as object but then I'd still be unable to cast them to pass typed parameters.

What reference do I need to add to my project and what using statement do I need to bring `Urn` into scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. There is a free-standing assembly

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
```

Urn is defined in there now.